# Separate object from origin deformation

Tags: mesh, objects

I have started using blender for rendering figures and I really love it.

The problem is that I reached a point I do not know how to resolve my issue. I wanted to bend a cylinder, so what I did was to use the "simply deform" modifier into a cylinder and use a circle for reference (Origin).

Now, I like the state of my new object, so I what to play with this mesh. The problem is that now, everytime I modify the object, is still based on that circle. Is there anyway I could have this object without modifiers but keeping the same shape ?

This way I could play with the transformation I got.

For example, I want to rotate the item but it's referencing the circle so the shape looks weird.

Thanks in advance

[image: Blender question]

Comment: Just apply the modifier . . ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In the upper left hand corner of the modifier pane, click the "apply" button, and this will make the modifications to the cylinder mesh permanent parts of the object.

Comment: Thank you, omg it was very easy! I cannot believe I didn't see it :S